# How to publish docusaurus website at username.github.io

Tags: github, web, markdown, github-pages, docusaurus

I have been learning how to use Docusaurus to make markdown documentation websites recently.
My exact questions are:

- How do I have to name the repository
- What do I have to change in this config: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WAhY.png
- What branch do I need for what?

My goal is to create a site at ruixey.github.io, not at ruixey.github.io/REPO_NAME/

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Docusaurus side

Everything I can see looks correct according to the documentation Docusaurus provides:
[Deploying to GitHub Pages | Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/docs/deployment#docusaurusconfigjs-settings).

It states the following about which branch is used:

> GitHub Pages picks up files from the default branch (**master/main**) or the **gh-pages** branch ...

and for deploying to the GH Page:

> We provide a `docusaurus deploy` command

### GitHub Pages side

Regarding your repository name, I recommend you to read the documentation that GitHub provides on Pages, which goes over the naming conventions when setting up a self-titled GitHub Pages deployment: [Creating a GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site)

These docs say the following about choosing a repository name:

> If you're creating a user site, your repository must be named `<user>.github.io` ...
> If your user name contains uppercase letters, you must **lowercase**
> the letters.

Source: [Creating a repository for your site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#creating-a-repository-for-your-site)

Have you tried to deploy with your current configuration file? I don't see a reason why it should fail.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to change in this config

Assuming your repo URI is something like: `git@github.com:Ruixey/roblox.git`

```
organizationName: 'Ruixey', // Usually your GitHub org/user name.
projectName: 'roblox', // Usually your repo name.
// git@github.com:Ruixey/roblox.git      <-- your ssh URI
//                 ^        ^
//      organizationName  projectName
```

> What branch do I need for what?

`main` for your source, when you deploy, `docusaurus` will push to `gh-pages` branch, if the branch does not exist, this creates it.

```bash
$ USE_SSH=true yarn deploy
```